# Spring rest docs for Rest service with JSONObject as @RequestParam

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest, spring-restdocs

I am trying to do write Spring rest docs for the rest service which accepts JSONObject as @RequestParam.
ex:

```
URL - http://localhost:9090/report?request={cdomain:automation,date:20190920}
```

Also I need to publish description for cdomain and date for understanding. 
I am able to generate the rest docs for @PathVariable with below code:

```
URL - http://localhost:9090/report/11

this.mockMvc.perform(RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.get("/report/{id}",1))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andDo(document("fin-report/balance-sheet",
                        pathParameters(parameterWithName("id")
                                .description("Identifier of the person to be obtained.")),
                        responseFields()...
```

Please let me know how to do documentation for JSONObject as @RequestParam, like below code and URL:

```
Code - @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json", path = "report)
    public String getReport(@RequestParam(value="request") JSONObject jobjparam) {...}

URL - http://localhost:9090/report?request={cdomain:automation,date:20190920}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "requestParameters in MockMvc not available"? You can add parameters to the request using the [`param(String, String…)` method](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.html#param-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-).

Comment: Please ignore the requestParameters part. Deleted the comment. You can help me with the question mentioned in the post